# Amazon SES explanation for "noise" in my hard bounce graph?

Tags: amazon-ses

I'm using SES to send emails for my small website project. On its busiest day, it sends 150 emails. Yet for some reason, SES shows continual fluctuation between 0% and 0.02% hard bounce rate.

Mathematically, these doesn't make sense, as even a single bounce would be 0.6% bounce rate (and that's per day, whereas this is on some smaller time scale).

What is the cause of this noise, and is there any solution to it, or do I just need to ignore it?

My SES charts from the past week:
[image: SES Bounce Chart][image: Number of sends]

Comment: I have this same problem, the bounce rate doesn't make sense.